# How to prove $|y|\le |\sin(z)|\le e^{|y|}$ in complex analysis where $z=x+iy$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to prove $$|y|\le |\sin(z)|\le e^{|y|}$$ in complex analysis where $z=x+iy$. I don't think I need the entire solution. May be just a set up or approach.

I started with sin(z) formula and reached a dead end or a reversed circle. I think the triangle inequality is useful for proving the second inequality and using a theorem if f(0) = g(0) and f(prime) (x) >= g(prime)(x) for x >=0 then f(x) >= g(x) for x>=0

Comment: I'd start with the formula $\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$.

Comment: I started and reached a dead end or a reversed circle. I think the triangle inequality is useful for proving the second inequality and using a theorem if f(0) = g(0) and f(prime) (x) >= g(prime)(x) for x >=0 then f(x) >= g(x) for x>=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\sin(z)=\sin(x+\textrm{i}\,y)=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+\textrm{i}\cos(x)\sinh(y)$$ and so $$\lvert\sin(z)\rvert^2=\sin(x)^2\cosh(y)^2+\cos(x)^2\sinh(y)^2.$$ Since $$\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2=1$$ this shows that $\lvert\sin(z)\rvert^2$ is a convex combination of $\cosh(y)^2$ and $\sinh(y)^2$. This observation provides lower and upper bounds for $\lvert\sin(z)\rvert^2$ and therfore also for $\lvert\sin(z)\rvert$.

Comment: But how does that prove that the upper and lower bounds are |y| and e^|y| ?

Comment: Well you didn't need the entire solution, right?  :-)  In fact this argument gives the better bounds $$\sinh \lvert y \rvert \leq \lvert \sin(z)\rvert \leq \cosh(y).$$

Comment: The better bounds is kind of straight forward. I have that solution. I was hoping to get an idea of how to get |y| out of sinh(y) and e^|y| out of cosh(y). 
http://s16.postimg.org/w538avotx/image.jpg

Comment: For $\cosh$ use that $e^{-y}\leq e^y$ for $y\geq 0$ and for $\sinh$ $$\sinh(y)=\int_0^y \cosh(t) \textrm{d}t\geq \int_0^y \textrm{d}t = y$$ for $y\geq 0$.

Comment: Got it now.
Thank you very much!